# d3 mouse event: using selection.node()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am studying this D3 example http://bl.ocks.org/JohnDelacour/5673836 (The code on this page is easier to read.)

In this function:

```
function follow_mouse() {
    var xy = d3.mouse(circle_01.node());
    var angle = (180/Math.PI * Math.atan2(xy[1], xy[0]));
    spoke_01.attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ")");
    report.text("Angle: " + angle.toFixed(2) + "°");
}
```

In line 2, why do we need `.node()` ?

I read [D3's document on d3.mouse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_mouse) but it did not help. Thank you.

```js
var w = 960,  h = 500 , r = 150;

// selection.on(type[, listener[, capture]])
// type: "mousemove"
// listener: follow_mouse
var svg = d3.select("html").append("svg")
 .attr({width: w, height: h}) // assign multiple attributes
 .on("mousemove", follow_mouse); // call function when mouse moves

// angle reading
var report = svg.append("text") .attr("id", "report")
 .attr({x: 80, y: 80})
 .text("Angle: 0.00°");

// g0 at center
var g0 = svg.append("g").attr("id", "g0")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + [w/2, h/2] + ")");

// draw arrow (path)
var spoke_01 = g0.append("path") .attr("id", "spoke_01")
 .attr("d", "M 0 0 h " + (r-2) + "l -9 3  2 -3 -2 -3 9 3");

// draw circle (circle)
var circle_01 = g0.append("circle").attr("id", "circle_01")
 .attr("r", r);


// https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_mouse
// this is an event listener. return value is ignored.
function follow_mouse() {
 var xy = d3.mouse(circle_01.node());
 var angle = (180/Math.PI * Math.atan2(xy[1], xy[0]));
 spoke_01.attr("transform", "rotate(" + angle + ")");
 report.text("Angle: " + angle.toFixed(2) + "°");
}
```

```css
svg {
 background-color: #ddf;
}
#circle_01 {
 fill: white;
 fill-opacity: 0;
 stroke: darkorchid;
 stroke-width: 2;
}
#spoke_01 {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #602;
 stroke-width: 2;
 stroke-linecap: round;
}
#report {
 fill: #602;
 stroke: none;
 font: 16pt sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link type="text/css" href="test.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="test.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because, as the documentation states,

> The container may be an HTML or SVG container element, such as an svg:g or svg:svg.

`circle_01` is a D3 selection, not a DOM element. Calling `.node()` on it gets the underlying DOM element.